# Draw markers on GMAPS API V3, and send location to Google Fusion

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I did a google maps api v3 drawing tool (polygons, lines, markers). Right now I am trying to make the markers I draw get inserted into a google fusion I created. I found out how to view markers I put on the fusion table. But I cant find anywhere any example concerning direct insert to google fusion, plus the documentation isnt helping me find out the correct way to use INSERT for google fusion. Is there something I should learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not yet possible to directly write to a fusion tables from the browser. You have 2 options:

1. Use a server side script to [POST your messages to Fusion Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059798/post-request-to-update-rows/10066881#10066881) or consider using the [PHP client library](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-php/)
2. Become a [trusted tester](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fusion-tables-api-trusted-testers), because with the new API it's possible to do it. Once your in the group you'll find example code from Google.